# Problem installing Fern 3.0 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I made sure I have all the prerequisites installed and I ran the execute.py file and terminal gave me this error:

```
michael@house-computer:~/Downloads/fern-wifi-cracker-3.0/Fern-Wifi-Cracker$ python3 execute.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execute.py", line 107, in <module>
    from core import *
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/fern-wifi-cracker-3.0/Fern-Wifi-Cracker/core/fern.py", line 11, in <module>
    from core import variables
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/fern-wifi-cracker-3.0/Fern-Wifi-Cracker/core/variables.py", line 64, in <module>
    os.mkdir(direc + log_direc)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/tmp/fern-log'
```

I tried to look up anything about this but there were no questions asked about the latest version of Fern (3.0)

Comment: I would start with `rm -rfv /tmp/fern-log` to see, if there are any ohter errors

Comment: I tried running it again and it said I had to run it as root so I did. Here's the whole ordeal: https://linx.li/poh1f6hb.txt